# Pact test on Junit5 what to define in @ExtendWith

Tags: java, junit, junit5, pact

I am starting with Pact testing, I have already my Consumer contract test and generates the JSON pact file.

The example I am following, has a test that runs the Pact file, Here is the example code I am following, it contains the provider (bs), consumer (client) and verifyer (which runs the Pact file) [pact example](https://github.com/mattiasmgn/Pact-JVM-Example)

```
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.PactRunner;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.Provider;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.State;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.loader.PactFolder;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.target.HttpTarget;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.target.Target;
import au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.target.TestTarget;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(PactRunner.class) 
@Provider("BusService") 
@PactFolder("../pacts")

public class BusStopContractTest {

    @State("There is a bus with number 613 arriving to Hammersmith bus station") 
    public void hammerSmith() {
        System.out.println("There is a bus with number 613 arriving to Hammersmith bus station" );
    }


    @TestTarget 
    public final Target target = new HttpTarget(8111);

}
```

I want to do the same, but for Junit5, so instead of ***@RunWith***, I need to use **@ExtendWith**, but what has to be defined inside **ExtendWith()**?

***@ExtendWith(PactRunner.class)*** does not work, I tried as well with ***@ExtendWith(PactConsumerTestExt.class)*** also didn´t work.

In my pom I have:

```
 <!-- Pact Provider-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
      <artifactId>pact-jvm-provider-junit_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.24</version>
    </dependency>
```

Junit Jupiter

```
<groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PactRunner` is a JUnit 4 runner. Instead, you need to use the JUnit 5 extension.

First, you need to add the JUnit 5 extension dependency to your `pom.xml`. E.g.:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
    <artifactId>pact-jvm-provider-junit5_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.24</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, you could use the `PactVerificationInvocationContextProvider`:

```
@ExtendWith(PactVerificationInvocationContextProvider.class)
@Provider("BusService") 
@PactFolder("../pacts")
public class BusStopContractTest {

    @State("There is a bus with number 613 arriving to Hammersmith bus station") 
    public void hammerSmith() {
        System.out.println("There is a bus with number 613 arriving to Hammersmith bus station" );
    }

    // A @BeforeEach method with an injected PactVerificationContext replaces
    // the old method annotated with @TestTarget
    @BeforeEach
    void setUpTarget(PactVerificationContext context) {
      context.setTarget(new HttpTarget(8111));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, I thought it could be enough to have the "jupiter dependencies" (I just included the dependencies as reference) , but I didn`t know that also I have to include junit5 it in the pact dependencies. Can I remove the jupiter dependencies? I have made the changes, but I can`t run the test class, it doesn`t have the option to "Run"

Comment: @andreahg You'll still need the jupiter dependencies in order to have the basic Jupiter capabilities. You should also check your Maven Surefire version - old version can't run Jupiter tests out of the box.

Comment: let me check it, that could be the reason why the test class is not runnable?

Comment: Is there another class I can use inside @ExtendWith, because PactVerificationInvocationContextProvider.class doesn`t make the class Runnable

Comment: Hi, the PactVerification class comes from ```<dependency>
            <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
            <artifactId>pact-jvm-provider-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>```